# install local database on my phone android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I finished my development of mobile (Android) applications using PhoneGap . I released version apk using PhoneGap builder to install it on my mobile. the problem is that my application offline as I use local database, how I can install this database in my app on my phone.

Eclipse is using DDMS file explorer, but on phone how does that happen?

Comment: Add your database file in the the `assets` folder and copy it to `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/databases/` at your app's first launch, then you can open the database as usual.

Comment: so I must restore my apk, and I add my database '00000000001. db 'folder in my asset?

Comment: Please if you have link of video or tuto, please give me and thks :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you dont need to install a database, you need to call openDatabase to create basic database, after that you need to create table and put in the values to them..

You can refer to the [API doc of Phone gap here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)...

Sample code :

```
function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

Comment: yes that's right, I already did and I already create my database. I am looking for how to copy the database from my pc to my mobile phone.

just copy and paste. ie how can I explore my phone as it is on Exlipse (DDMS-> File explorer-> data-> ...)

Comment: @B.M.A : To explore the database you have to goto /data/data/<your package name>/databases/<your database.db>. To explore it on phone, you need to root your phone and access /data folder